# Yii2 роут для категорий неограниченной вложенности

Tags: php, yii2, маршрутизация

Возникла проблема при получении урла подобного типа -

/category/category/category/category/category

Точнее как прописать правило не очень понятно, сейчас так

```
'<slug:[\w-]+>' => 'category/view',
```

но срабатывает только если /category, т.е. один параметр, если 2 к примеру уже не работает, т.е. так /category/category2 уже не срабатывает.

Можно прописать так конечно

```
'<slug:[\w-]+>' => 'category/view',
'<slug:[\w-]+>/<slug2:[\w-]+>' => 'category/view',
'<slug:[\w-]+>/<slug2:[\w-]+>/<slug3:[\w-]+>' => 'category/view',
```

Но мне совсем не нравится такой подход. Можете подсказать что нибудь поэлегантнее ?

Comment: Нашел, статья по теме http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/33/generaciia-url-dlia-vlojennih-kategorii-v-yii , может кому еще пригодится 

Собственно что меня интересовало 


`'<slug:[\w_\/-]+>' => 'category/view'`

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел, [статья по теме](http://elisdn.ru/blog/33/generaciia-url-dlia-vlojennih-kategorii-v-yii) , может кому еще пригодится.

Собственно что меня интересовало, получаем всю строку запроса

```
'<slug:[\w_\/-]+>'
```